# Файл .zip скачивается без имени

Tags: python, django, zip

Делаю в приложении раздел с файлами и реализую в нём возможность скачивать всё одним архивом. Архив создается, файлы туда записываются, но беда в том, что, при попытке его скачать, он скачивается с именем `"Без имени.zip"`, хотя имя в папке на сервере ему задается нормально. Я уже часа 2 штудирую различную документацию, но пока не вижу ничего, что могло бы мне помочь. `iri_to_uri()` не работает, `encode()` тоже пробовал, но видимо дело не только в символах.

```
def DownloadAllFilesView(request, objId):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        project_folder = Doc.objects.filter(idProj=Project.objects.get(id=objId)).first().idProj.name.replace(' ', '_')
        path = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/projects/project_%s/' % project_folder
        z_name = '%s.zip' % Project.objects.get(id=objId).name.replace(' ', '_')    # сейчас здесь находится путь до папки media, где будет лежать архив

        z = zipfile.ZipFile(settings.MEDIA_ROOT+'/projects/archs/'+z_name, 'w')
        z.filename = z_name    # изменяю filename архива на нужное, в папке media все работает

        for file in os.listdir(path):
            z.write(os.path.join(path, file), arcname=file)    # запись файлов в архив

        z.close()

        return FileResponse(open(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT+'/projects/archs/', z.filename), 'rb'))
```

Кто с такой проблемой уже сталкивался, помогите, пожалуйста! Спасибо!

Comment: попробуй в разных местах просмотреть значение переменной, отвечающей за имя архива (`print(z.filename)`)

Comment: Спасибо, что откликнулись, но я уже все решил, хоть ничего и не понял толком)
Я забыл установить в FileResponse as_attachment=True, когда поставил, все заработало.